# Can anyone identify this object?

Tags: accidents, accident-investigation

In La Réunion, people are currently searching for plane debris that could be from the MH370 crash and this morning [this object](http://www.linfo.re/la-reunion/faits-divers/674376-enquete-mh370-un-debris-retrouve-sur-le-littoral-de-st-denis) was found.
[image: Image found at la Réunion]

Can anyone identify it?

Comment: There is an unfortunately huge amount of junk just kind of floating around in the sea, and since this isn't obviously a large airplane part...it's hard to say if it's from MH370 or not.  It'll have to be take to a lab for analysis before anyone can really say anything.  (For more info on random junk in the sea: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Pacific_garbage_patch)

Comment: @JayCarr That's surely something to keep in mind ! Thank you.

Comment: its a toilet seat!

Comment: It's probably the remains of a [Kenmore 325 sewing machine](http://www.ebay.com/itm/KENMORE-325-12514-Portable-Mechanical-Sewing-Machine-/221537993011)

Comment: @rbp [From the space station](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6sx5D76nLdk)?

Comment: Could be of of the overhead plastic panels which house the lights etc

Answer (score 3):

We really shouldn't speculate, but it does not look like a panel piece for a door or window. Aside from two small warning lights on some models there shouldn't be very much.

This is very much speculation: Aside from the deep inset, which looks like it could have housed a CRT monitor, there are two holes for square aviation-style switches, and two holes, perhaps for backlighting, above it. The left hole looks very similar to an SD card slot.

Then again, it could have come from a boat or anything.

Comment: Really interesting, thank you !

Comment: DeltaLima is right. See [It's a sewing machine](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3185568/Is-plane-window-thought-MH370-actually-sewing-machine-Police-Reunion-Island-not-convinced-white-object-missing-Malaysia-Airlines-plane.html)